# 403 forbidden access wordpress after login

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

I am facing a strange behavior of the 403 forbidden access using wordpress  locally on an Archlinux machine.
I installed Apache, mysql, and php following several online guides, and
I downloaded wordpress and placed it in /srv/http/wordpress.

The first strange thing happens when it was the time to install wordpress. The guides said to type localhost/wordpress and follow the form, but I had the 403 error. To install wordpress I had to type the entire path to the install.php page.
After having installed wp, I did the login and again I had the 403 error.
Therefore, I try to type the entire path to the index.php within the wp-admin folder, and I was able to enter the admin panel.

These are the following issues that I am facing:

1. I get 403 error if I type localhost/wordpress/wp-admin
2. If I type localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php I get the login page, but after the login I am looped back to the same login page
3. To get the admin panel I have to type /localhost/wordpress/login.php, perform the login, get the 403 error page, and type /localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php

I tried to reinstall wordpress without success.
I also tried to give permission 777 to all the folders and file without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to check your apache httpd.conf

```
<Directory /srv/http/wordpress>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

chmod 777 is not a good practice... you should find out what uid & gid are running apache and make sure it's the owner or has necessary permission to /srv/httpd/wordpress

Comment: I think I solved the problem following your suggestion. My httpd.conf file was containing two different rows: `Require all granted` and options row had only `Options FollowSymlinks`

Comment: I think missing Indexes was the probably issue, apache doesn't look for an index page under this directory without that option.  Glad I could help!